# How do I move a player around a grid in my JavaScript game?

Tags: javascript, rotation, grid

In the interface of the game I'm making, the player moves their mouse in the direction they want the character to move.

The degree value (like 90 for east) is sent back to the game server.

When the function `move` is called, I want the player's x and y positions to change based on the degree value.

So, `move(90, 0, 0)` would return `{x:1, y:0}` and `move(45, 8, 14)` could return `{x:8.something, y:14.something}`.

The code needs to be JavaScript, and look something like this:

```js
function move(degree, currentX, currentY) {
  //Complicated maths things with pi and circles and stuff
  return {x:newX,y:newY};
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to figure it out yourself? SO is not a free code-writing service.

Comment: No, the parameters are the angle I want to move in, the x from, and y from. I have no idea how to convert something like 90 degrees into `move 1 square right and 0 squares up`. I assume it has something to do with trigonometry.